# Phonegap show login page only first time

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm working on a phonegap application and I want to only display the login page(index.html) if they are logging in for the first time. Once they login they should never be presented with that page even if they exit out and reopen.

I currently have a boolean in localStorage that keeps track of whether they are authenticated or not. If they are

```
$(function (){
if (window.localStorage.is_authenticated){
    window.location.replace('member_card.html');
} });
```

The problem with this is that if a user navigates to login by closing and opening the app the login screen flashes/flickers and then goes to the member_card page.

Is there anyway to smoothen this transition or not show the login page?

Comment: instead of showing the login page as the first page and redirect if the is_authenticated, do it the other way, load member_card.html as primary page, and if the is_authenticated is false redirect to the login page

Comment: Thanks! This is a good and easy solution

Answer (score -1):

What you will have to do is run the javascript that looks at is_authenticated as soon as possible. At the moment it sounds like that the JS runs once the page has loaded/rendered before navigating to the next page.

Another  way is to redefine the logic and have the log in screen on a separate page and make index the member_card page. IE only go to the log in page if the user is not logged in rather than the other way around.

Finally look into single page web design. While it won't remove the transition, it will reduce it by a fair amount. I have been using [Roadcrew.js](https://grobmeier.github.io/Roadcrew.js/) with a fair amount of success.

Comment: The code above already fires when the page is loaded. That however is the problem. If the page loads then it will flash for a split second. If I change index to be member_card and redirect to login if they are not authenticated then it will flash member_card for a split second as well. Correct me if I'm wrong. I can look into a single pag design

Comment: That is correct. There is no real way to get around it. You could use a splash screen for both and then switch to the correct page after a small delay (EG 2 seconds). It is all about choosing the the best compromise.

Comment: I decided to make the member card page the index file and redirect to login once